# How do I access a particular model in the templateHelper of a Collection View (or Layout)?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, scope, marionette

Roughly I have something like this:

```
my collection; //a collection of models with ids 

Layout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
    templateHelpers: {
        myFunc: function() {
             //this.items is an array of the serialized models in collection
        }
    }
})

layout = new Layout({
    collection: collection,

})
```

The problem is that in `myFunc()` I can see the model data in my collection: it is available as an array this.items. But there is no key so I cannot do something like `this.items.get("the_one_i_want")`.

How can i access an individual model in this case?

( In this case it doesn't really suit to use a composite view and an item view and put the template helper on the item view. )

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm misunderstanding, but it seems to me that maybe what you're looking for are the "container methods" of in Marionette, listed here: http://marionettejs.com/docs/backbone.marionette.html under "container methods".

So if you have a collection of models with IDs, rather than

```
this.items.get('the_one_you_want')
```

you'd write something like

```
this.items.findByIndex('my_index')
```

I've never personally used findByIndex and there's a little warning "This is not guaranteed to be a stable index." but you can also search by a few other things, including CID and the Model itself.

Again, I may not fully understand your situation, but I hope that provides some help...
Ian

Answer (score 0):

You're creating the Layout with a `collection` property, so you'll have access to `this.collection` within the Layout. From there you should be able to filter it however you want, for example:

```
this.collection.filter(function(model) {
  return model.get('id') == 'id_you_want';
});
```

As I understand it, `this.items` is just `this.collection` mushed into an array.

For a nice practical example of this functionality, have a look at **[this section](https://github.com/derickbailey/todomvc/blob/marionette/labs/architecture-examples/backbone_marionette/js/TodoMVC.Layout.js)** from [Derick Bailey's fork](https://github.com/derickbailey/todomvc) of the [TodoMVC](http://todomvc.com/) project. Note how he sets up a filter via a `getCompleted()` function on the collection, then calls `this.collection.getCompleted()` from the Layout. That code should point you in the right direction.

Comment: The problem is this.items is just that - an Array. With numeric indicies. So this.items.get(myId) throws an error. There is no method get. Inside of templateHelpers there is no sight of this.collection because 'this' is is templateHelpers object - not the layout. So, essentially the problem seems to be how to access the layout instance from within templateHelpers given that 'this' has been comandeered by templateHelpers.

Comment: You have a couple options for recapturing the `this` you want. One is to use the javascript [apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) function. For example: `layout.templateHelpers.myFunc.apply(layout)` will make it so you can access your collection as `this.collection` from within myFunc.